# Norm of vector in directional derivate

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

Reading about the derivatives according to a direction, I found a definition saying that the norm of the vector v in the formula $\nabla_{\mathbf{v}}{f}(\mathbf{x}) = \lim_{h \to 0}{\frac{f(\mathbf{x} + h\mathbf{v}) - f(\mathbf{x})}{h}}$ must necessarily be 1. Why is this needed? If the vector norm is different, what happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The norm of $\mathbf{v}$ need not be $1$. What happens is that it is sufficient to know $\nabla_{\mathbf{v}}{f}(\mathbf{x})$ when $\mathbf{v}$ has norm $1$.

Indeed, for $\mathbf{v}$ of norm $1$ and $c\in\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ we have
$$
\nabla_{c\mathbf{v}}{f}(\mathbf{x}) = \lim_{h \to 0}{\frac{f(\mathbf{x} + hc\mathbf{v}) - f(\mathbf{x})}{h}}=c \lim_{h \to 0}{\frac{f(\mathbf{x} + hc\mathbf{v}) - f(\mathbf{x})}{ch}}=c\nabla_{\mathbf{v}}{f}(\mathbf{x}).
$$

Comment: To be clear: it is sufficient to know the derivative for any particular norm of v, 1 is just a nice choice.

Comment: Sure, I meant nonzero norm, thanks :)